# Convert `20180801 21:10:12.016` format to timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

How does suggestion for parse sample `20180801 21:10:12.016` date with javascript or jquery and convert it to the timestamp?

I try `Date`, `new Date`, `parse()`,... but don't return correction values. and return `Invalid Date` or `NaN`.

The correct value is: `1533141612016` (for my local time)

I know about `new Date("2018-08-01 21:10:12.016").getTime()` but a little difference with my date format. So I write this code:

```
var _o = "20180801 21:10:12.016";
const regex = /([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\ (.+)/gm;
var _x = regex.exec(_o);
_x = _x[1] + '-' + _x[2] + '-' + _x[3] + ' ' + _x[4];
_x = Date.parse(_x);
console.log(_x);
```

But it's complicated, Do you have any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider using Moment.js?

This library will save you a lot of time and trouble handling dates ;)

```js
const input = "20180801 21:10:12.016";
const output = moment(input, "YYYYMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
console.log(output);
console.log(output.valueOf());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Source: https://momentjs.com